# How to test using CMake that a C++ application has no memory errors?

Tags: c++, cmake, ctest

I have a C++ project in CMake and I have implemented unit tests (using GoogleTest) as well as integration tests i.e. executing applications and checking the results using regexp e.g.

```
add_test(NAME MyAppIntegration.testRefitRunMse COMMAND my_application "--refit=true")
set_tests_properties(MyAppIntegration.testRefitRunMse PROPERTIES PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "mse\\=1\\.53611e\\-05")
```

Now I would like to do the same as above but running the application to detect memory errors e.g. simply run `./my_application` and check for memory errors with valgrind. How can I do that? Note that I am aware of `ctest -D ExperimentalMemCheck` and `ctest -T memcheck` but here I end up with the error `Cannot find file DartConfiguration.tcl` which seems related to the Dashboard configuration that I don't need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I found a possible solution. Adding these lines to my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
## valgrind
find_program(CTEST_MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND NAMES valgrind)
INCLUDE(Dart)
```

generates the needed `DartConfiguration.tcl` whatever that is, and then re-invoking:

```
ctest -T memcheck
```

runs all tests also checking for memory errors.